# use np.stack to add more bands (dimensions) to an exisiting ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, dimensions

I want to append 2 more 2-d arrays ,each one with shape of (1, 777, 458) ,to an exisiting ndarray with the shape of (14, 777, 458).

I have tried to use np.dstack in order to do that:

```
np.dstack((arr_14,arr_1a,arr_1b))
```

But then I have gotten the error:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis
> must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has
> size 14 and the array at index 1 has size 1

I found a way to "solve" it, by using np.stack and get each array:

```
all_data=np.stack((arr_14[0],arr_14[1],arr_14[2],arr_14[3],arr_14[4],arr_14[5],arr_14[6],arr_14[7],       arr_14[8],arr_14[9],arr_14[10],arr_14[11],arr_14[12],arr_14[13],arr_1a[0],arr_1b[0]))
```

**that worked, but I want to know if there is better way to do the dame things, without extracting each band of the image.**

Comment: try `np.concatenate(( arr14, arr1a, arr1b ), axis=0 )`

Comment: `dstack` stacks along the third axis, you want to stack along the first axis, i.e. use `vstack` (or `concatenate` as suggested above)